# How to fix Visual Studio C# WPF not supporting hint assist

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm relatively new to C# WPF programming and I've been trying to write a simple app using Material Design in xaml (using the `MaterialDesignThemes` nuget package).

I was trying to get a password box using the documentation provided by the `MaterialDesignInXaml` demo itself, but I keep getting this error

> Hintassist is not supported in WPF

This is the piece of code that I try to run:

```
<TextBox
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperText="Helper text"
     materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Text (validated)"
     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextBox}">
```

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

But obviously there's some error with the `HintAssist` feature here. This same error comes up in other features, too, like buttonassist, but it's mainly problematic in this situation.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of "is not supported in WPF" is unclear to you?

Comment: OK I found [the source code](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/HintAssist.cs), and it seems like it should be supported.  Try the usual: restart Visual Studio, delete the bin, obj, and .vs directories, recreate your project file and solution file, etc.

Comment: Are you missing or used the wrong reference for material design?  Think that should be xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes

Comment: WPF supports Hintassist. It is possible that your xaml format does not meet the requirements. You can try using a minimal example to check if the issue is related to configuration`<TextBox
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Text="Your Text"
     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextBox}">
     <TextBox.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip Content="Helper text"/>
     </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>`